# What happens to GTA online progress from PS3 to PS4?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, psn

Does your progress get reset or is it accessible on PS4 when you upgrade?

Comment: Are you talking about character transfers? Because you can't do that anymore.  It was discontinued in March.

Comment: @TimmyJim I think that's what they're talking about. Would seem they tried to move their account to PS4 along with upgrading their console. You're right they discontinued that.

Answer (score 1):

The deadline for character transfer from PS3 to PS4 was March 6, 2017.  If you haven't transferred yet, then you're out of luck.

If you did transfer already, then the PS3 account progress was cloned to the PS4 account, at which point they became separate entities. Subsequent progress on one platform does not transfer to the other.